# Pyodbc Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-access, pyodbc

Estou com um certo problema em utilizar o `pyodbc` para conectar em um MS Access.

Até poucos dias atrás, estava tudo operando normalmente, porém após a atualização do meu Anaconda, passou a ocorrer um erro persistente no sistema.

```
Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

No caso, segue um trecho do código:

```
import pyodbc

def conn_cur_access_db(path, base):
    access_conn_str = "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ={}{}".format(path,base)
    print(access_conn_str)
    conn = pyodbc.connect(access_conn_str)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    return conn, cur

#nome do arquivo e diretório alterados
path = r"G:\my\db\path"
base = "mydb.accdb"
conn, cur = conn_cur_access_db(path, base)

# do something
conn.close()
cur.close()
del conn
del cur
```

Quando eu faço a primeira conexão, até funciona, mas a partir da segunda tentativa de conexão (mesmo tendo fechado a conexão com o banco de dados) no Tracerback tem:

```
<ipython-input-1-827e414c3c0e> in conn_cur_access_db(path, base)
      4     access_conn_str = "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ={}{}".format(path,base)
      5     print(access_conn_str)
----> 6     conn = pyodbc.connect(access_conn_str)
      7 
      8     return conn

Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

Cheguei a pesquisar na internet, mas não achei nada sobre esse erro no MS Access

**UPDATE**

Eu fiz um teste

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        conn, cur = conn_cur_access_db(path, base)
        with conn:
            with cur:
                print("A")
                print(conn, cur)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        conn, cur = conn_cur_access_db(path, base)
        with conn:
            with cur:
                print("B")
                print(conn, cur)
```

e o resultado:

```
A
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E030> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C181B0>
A
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E100> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C182B0>
('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
B
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E030> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C18230>
('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
B
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E100> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C18330>
('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
B
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E030> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C182B0>
('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
B
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E100> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C181B0>
('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
B
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E030> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C18330>
('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
B
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E100> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C18230>
('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
B
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E030> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C181B0>
('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
B
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000016000C1E100> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000016000C182B0>
```

Comment: Não tem outra opção além do ODBC? Pessoalmente falando, odeio ODBC...  
Enfim... 
Pelo menos esse trecho do código não tem nada de errado. você está chamando novamente conn, cur = conn_cur_access_db(path, base)? Imo seria melhor fazer uma classe para a conexão para não ficar escrevendo o mesmo código várias vezes. Se tiver algum problema está no resto do código btw.

Comment: Na verdade, esta função está dentro de uma classe de funções bem repetidas, e infelizmente é ms access mesmo, não tenho como mudar o banco de dados da empresa.

Comment: Então será necessário refatoração para orientação a objeto, facilitando depuração do código. Senão, vai ter que procurar o bug. Pois alguma linha de código não está permitindo a finalização de streaming do arquivo .accdb. Se o driver não posta um erro é exatamente porque não obteve sucesso no streaming do arquivo. É coisa de 10min. para fazer uma classe com serviço CRUD, e é bem mais confiável do que código estruturado

Comment: Esqueci de falar.. Outra coisa,  algumas vezes pode ter atualizado o módulo pyodbc por conta da atualização do anaconda. E algum comando do pyodbc pode ter mudado. Se for isso, utilize um ambiente virtual com a versão correta, ou arrume o código para funcionar na versão mais recente

Comment: Neste caso, o erro ocorre na string de conexão, ou seja, antes de abrir conexão com o banco de dados. Será que é algum problema na hora de fazer o conn.close()? Já que ocorre o problema quando vai abrir o banco de dados novamente.

Comment: Poderia responder algum código para ver como exemplo?

Comment: Só vou ter tempo de dar uma olhada nisso final de semana :\ trampo+facul tá matando